# Django forms - cleaned_data KeyError

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form that looks like the following:

```
class AForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email1 = forms.EmailField(required=False, initial='')
    email2 = forms.EmailField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = AModel
        fields = ()

    def clean_email1(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['email1'].lower()

    def clean_email2(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['email2'].lower()

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(AForm, self).clean()
        email1 = cleaned_data['email1']   # ERR
        email2 = cleaned_data['email2']
        # ...
```

It is used in a view `post` method in the following way:

```
form = AForm(request.POST, instance=self.object)
if forms.is_valid():
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```

It happens sometimes that my users produce a `KeyError` in `clean` at the line marked with `ERR`.

I don't understand how this is possible since, [as the documentation reads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data), cleaned_data should contain (as dict keys) all the fields of the form.

Also I can't reproduce the error when I test sending nothing for `email1` and `email2` (or blank/empty values).

What am I missing here?

Comment: As I re-read the documentation, I understand finally that it means that `cleaned_data` should include all the keys **after `form.is_valid()`** (I didn't look into the code yet about when exactly it is filled with all the keys). Yet, I wonder how to reproduce the error

Comment: Is this a typo? cleaned_data = super(PUWForm_fwd, self).clean() The name of the class is AForm.

Comment: @JonS. right, a typo

Comment: I hit this issue because I incorrectly expected `clean()` not to be called if any individual `clean_field()` calls failed. In my case, `raise ValidationError` meant the field didn't appear in `cleaned_data` in `clean()` but I didn't know the validation had failed because it's normally displayed as an error in the form.

Answer (score 4):

You've explicitly marked email1 as required=False. That means it's perfectly possible to get to clean with no value for that field, in which case it will not be included in the cleaned_data dict.

To guard against that, you can use the normal dict `get` method:

```
email1 = cleaned_data.get('email1')
```

or, of course, you could make the field required.

Comment: But what about what's written at the link to the django doc that I mentioned in the question?